# Copy Constructor with Default Constructor in Java

Tags: java, copy-constructor, default-constructor

I need to have a copy constructor in my class as i need to create duplicate objects. I believe that if i will create a copy constructor, I will have to specify the non parameterized constructor too as Java will no longer provide the default constructor.

I don't want to touch the default constructor as that is what i being used in the code everywhere. Is there a workaround to have either a copy constructor or something like it without defining the basic constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, if you want to have both a parameterless constructor *and* a constructor with parameters, you need to declare them both. It's very easy to declare the parameterless constructor though:

```
public YourClassName() {
}
```

The `super();` is implicit.

That will behave exactly the same way as the default constructor would, although it won't necessarily have the same access as the default constructor. (You can change it from being `public` if you want, of course.) From the [JLS section 8.8.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9):

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor with no formal parameters and no throws clause is implicitly declared.
>
> If the class being declared is the primordial class Object, then the default constructor has an empty body. Otherwise, the default constructor simply invokes the superclass constructor with no arguments.
>
> It is a compile-time error if a default constructor is implicitly declared but the superclass does not have an accessible constructor (§6.6) that takes no arguments and has no throws clause.
>
> In a class type, if the class is declared public, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier public (§6.6); if the class is declared protected, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier protected (§6.6); if the class is declared private, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier private (§6.6); otherwise, the default constructor has the default access implied by no access modifier.

Comment: Thanks Jon. but will the above constructor initialize the members to default values properly. I mean without specifying those default values in this parameterless constructor.

Comment: A constructor declared as in this answer does exactly what a compiler generated default constructor would have done,

Answer (score 3):

If you really do not want to write the default constructor, you can do:

```
public static MyClass create(MyClass original) {
    // return the new instance
}
```